# what is the purpose of , and . in statistical/matrix notation?

Tags: matrices, statistics, notation

I feel like this has got to be a trivial question, but I'm not having any luck searching for the answer.  I went down an absorbing Markov chain rabbithole yesterday, and in multiple places I saw equation/variable/matrix definitions with either a `,` or a `.` at the end, but no context as to what it means.  None of the charts I can find on statistical notation mention either of those characters.  There are multiple examples available on [the absorbing Markov chain Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain), and I also ran across other pages that used notation like `p,` and `q,`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Just a punctuation mark, to make the sentence grammatically correct. E.g. In equation in [Canonical Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Canonical_form) section of your link, they say "Then P = <matrix>, where Q is ...". This comma is simply required here.

Comment: They're punctuation, nothing more. In those cases, the intention is to read the equation as part of a sentence, and so commas and periods are used for grammatical reasons. There is a different convention where displayed equations never have punctuation, regardless of whether it is meant to be read as part of an existing sentence. The linked page (and many others) do not follow that convention.

Comment: This is just English language punctuation, I believe.

Comment: @Hayden, that convention makes way more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just normal English punctuation, where periods terminate sentences and commas delineate lists or clauses.  The sentences happen to include mathematical notation, and the punctuation stands out when the mathematics appears as a display.

Comment: Well now I feel even sillier.  When I'm in charge, everyone will follow the "no punctuation in an equation ever" rule.  It's really confusing when it's the same font and size as the equation and not the text it's part of.  I actually lost a fair bit of time trying to wrap my head around that.